# How do I populate this placeholder info for a GoDaddy email form?

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts, send

I am using the template code below for my website and am having trouble getting the contact form email to send.

```
require_once "Mail.php";
// Change this options:
$username = 'user@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';
$smtpHost = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$smtpPort = '465';
$to = 'user@gmail.com';
$from = 'user@gmail.com';
```

How would I go about replacing the placeholder info with a GoDaddy email?

I've tried several methods but my 'send' button does nothing.

Do I really need to enter my email username and passport on this form?

Why would I need to specify who the email is from if it being entered in the form?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using PEAR mail to send using an external SMTP server. This is doable and is often one of the easiest ways to send email using PHP. Your code is incomplete, since I don't see anything to actually send the mail. But to answer your other questions:

First, you *really do* need to enter your email username and passport in order to send the email, because it is used for authentication to the SMTP server. *DO NOT* enter it on the HTML form, keep it hidden inside the PHP script.

Second, for the "from", do not use the email entered for this. Rather, set the "from" to whatever email address you want it to appear as the mail is being sent from, such as your email (gmail) address here. Often the SMTP server will reject the message if it is not from the same address that you use as the login. Not sure if gmail does this as I've never used their SMTP server, but this is the sort of thing they would do. I'd imagine GoDaddy probably does this too.

Enter the user's email as a new, optional field, the `Reply-To` field. This will be convenient for you because you can just hit "Reply" on the message and it'll go to the right user.

I personally am more partial to the object-oriented way of using PEAR. Here's how I would code it:

```
require_once(`Mail.php');
$headers['From']    = 'Your Name <your_email@whateverdomain.com>';
$headers['To']      = $recipients;
$headers['Subject'] = "$subject";
$headers['Date']    = date('r', time()); // Auto-generate date
$headers['Reply-To'] = "$email_from_form";

$params['host'] = 'ssl://smtp.yourhost.com'; // Look this up from your SMTP provider
$params['port'] = '465'; // This may need to be changed with some providers, look it up in the provider's documentation
$params['auth'] = true; // Nearly always needs to be true nowadays
$params['username'] = 'username'; // Look this up from your SMTP provider
$params['password'] = 'password';

$mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);

$output=$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

// Error handling
if(PEAR::isError($output))
{
    $error=$output->getMessage();
    // Do whatever you want with this error. I output it during setup / configuration, then on the live production server I store it in a log or database that I check regularly.
}
```

For troubleshooting, just break it down into pieces. If PEAR generates an error, check it and you can figure out what to do. If you get an error before that, hopefully it'll help you figure out what is going on. And, before any of this, verify that the submitted web form is properly collecting info.

Collect these from `$_POST` variables. Like `$email_from_form=$_POST['email'];` and such.

Lastly, *before you make this go live* look up security of email contact forms. You will find that attackers will start trying to do sketchy things with your form almost as soon as it is launched. You absolutely *must* implement some security or you will quickly find your email address that the form is sent to, is filled with bizarre spam and hacking attempts.

At a bare minimum, run some checks on the data you are being submitted. I implement a complex series of anti-spam measures on any web content form, from fake fields to timing to cryptographic hashes that prevent robots from bookmarking forms. Even then, some spam still gets through. You need to be very careful these days.